# Future Method Has No Data

Tags: mysql, flutter, flutter-futurebuilder

I have one future method for fetch data from mysql database. I am using FutureBuilder and if snqpshot has no data return circular progress else my ui. But i see only circular progress. Here my future method.

```html
  Future _getData() async {
  Mysql db = Mysql();
  db.getConnection().then((conn) async {
    debugPrint('User ID: $uid');
    var correctStats =
        await conn.query('select correctCount from users where uid = "$uid"');
    for (var row in correctStats) {
      correctCountStats = row[0];
    }
    var wrongStats =
        await conn.query('select wrongCount from users where uid = "$uid"');
    for (var row in wrongStats) {
      wrongCountStats = row[0];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Show what your future builder looks like..
In this case snapshot will have no data hence your circular loading. Your future isn't returning anything :)

Comment: what do you want to get from FutureBuilder? @BatuhanDelice

Answer (score 0):

You arent returning the db. you can do
I prefer using `await`

```dart
Future _getData() async {
  Mysql db = Mysql();

  final conn = await db.getConnection();
  debugPrint('User ID: $uid');
  var correctStats =
      await conn.query('select correctCount from users where uid = "$uid"');
  for (var row in correctStats) {
    correctCountStats = row[0];
  }
  var wrongStats =
      await conn.query('select wrongCount from users where uid = "$uid"');
  for (var row in wrongStats) {
    wrongCountStats = row[0];
  }
  return db;
}
```

Comment: You like to return db from it? check second one

Comment: Glad to help, also you needed to return from `return ...then((conn) async {....return db;` for that case I belive